# Redux toolkit delete function using filter method

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

```
const storeListSlice = createSlice({
  name: "storeListSlice",

  initialState: {
    list: []
  },

reducer : filterList: (state, action) => {
      state.list.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload);
    },
```

```
const storeListSlice = createSlice({
  name: "storeListSlice",

  initialState: {
    list: []
  },
reducer : filterList: (state, action) => {
      const test = state.list.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload);
      state.list = test;
    },
```

I'm implementing the delete function with Redux Toolkit.

When implemented with the first code, it wasn't reflected on the screen except for refresh.

When done in the second way, it is properly reflected on the screen.

When I made the TO DO list for practice, I used the first method to delete it.

I don't understand why it should be implemented like the second method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to explain this is in the first code example you gave the new filtered state is not being returned explicitly, while in the second example it is since you're setting `state.list = test`.

Another cleaner way of writing it would simply be to use:

```
const storeListSlice = createSlice({
  name: "storeListSlice",

  initialState: {
    list: []
  },

reducer : filterList: (state, action) => {
      **return state.list.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload);**
    },
```